# IE quirks mode: width: auto

Tags: css, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

The problem I've encountered is - in IE on a floated element `width: auto;` does nothing - I've got to set up the width automatically for ie(quirks mode).

How can I set the width automatically in IE quirks mode for a floated element so the parent container would extend accordingly to the longest child in width?

Comment: Any particular reason you care about quirks mode? Perhaps you're working on an ancient site?

Comment: To cut a long story short - yes :).

Comment: Fair enough then, I'm sorry for your predicament. Could you make a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo showing the problem?

Comment: Thanks, thirtydot. As I will get back home from my work I will post it. However the result can be described easily - the child elements wrap and I would like to have the container expand to fit the text. On standarts mode or other browsers "width: auto;" does the job. For IE quirks mode - it doesn't..

Comment: Perhaps you can use `display:inline-block` instead? ( With the IE fixes for inline-block oddity, that is )

Comment: what version(s) of IE do you need to support? (this may make a big difference to the available solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Of course I'm not aware of the full situation But.. this could do it.

Setting `float: left;` to the parent element or `float: right;` also more or less establishes the "contents" limits / dimensions.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ycbcZ/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ycbcZ/2/ - Useless addition but if you click the red box you'll see that the parent sticks with it..